# powershell get-childitem path format is not supported error

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Powershell 5.1 on Windows 7 sp1 throws the error below:

Snippet:

```bsh
$Lstfile= @(Get-ChildItem 'G:\BACKUPS\' -Filter *.zip | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 )
```

Error:

```
Get-ChildItem : The given path's format is not supported.
At C:\DailyBackup.ps1:101 char:13
+ $Lstfile= @(Get-ChildItem "G:\BACKUPS\" -Filter *.zip | sort LastWrit ...

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Goal is timestamp of LAST backup file created (with the filter "*.zip").                              Tried at least a dozen different ways to derive last modified data, all throw the same (or similar) error "Given path's format is not supported"
And yes, "G:\Backups" does exist.
THANX.

Comment: Does it work if you prepend the argument with the intended parameter name, ie: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'G:\BACKUPS\' ...` or `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'G:\BACKUPS\' ...`

Comment: Maybe some unprintable character sneaked into your script file? Try rewriting the line from scratch. Also. what do you get when you run `dir g:`? or `dir g:\backups` without the filter?

Comment: What result do you get from Get-PsDrive G

Comment: Sorry.  It was the "G" drive.  Powershell can't do anything with that drive, so I moved my Backups directory to another drive.  Now it works.